# UIWebView didn't quite finish loading

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have pushed a view onto my nav controller that contains a UIWebView and this will load a URL.

When it starts I kick off the networkActivityIndicatorVisible and when it finishes I hide it.

If a user decides he does not want to finish loading the web page and hits back on the navcontroller the network indicator carries on.  How do I get rid of this as there appears to be no delegate method for this and none of the viewdidUnload get triggered....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about making the activity indicator invisible in previous controller's viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated?

Comment: Thanks, I was being a muppet then and missed off the :(BOOL)animated and I take it that is required....

Answer (score 2):

In the viewWillDisappear: method of your UIWebView's ViewController, do this

```
if([yourWebView isLoading]){
  //hide your network activity indicator
  [yourWebView stopLoading];
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: As below, I was being a muppet then and missed off the :(BOOL)animated and I take it that is required....

I have added both bits of code.

Answer (score 2):

I did a simple solution of reference counting for the loading processes:

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    if (_loadRef == 0) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    }

    _loadRef++;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    _loadRef--;

    if (_loadRef == 0) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    }
}
```